# HD numbers according to the positions

Tags: naming

Which database matches HD numbers (or other names) with positions of stars? I would like to insert the list of positions. Gaia does not provide that, right? Thank you

I tried SIMBAD and obtained
[image]

Comment: is SIMBAD what you are looking for? https://simbad.u-strasbg.fr/simbad/sim-fid

Comment: Your screenshot looks like you want to do reverse search: from position to catalogue number? That said: not every HD catalogue entry is a real entry - and that is indicated in simbad's answers: https://cdsarc.cds.unistra.fr/ftp/cats/III/182/errors.htx

Comment: So, it is not possible to obtain a name by entering the coordinates?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like SIMBAD has a way to automate this with a list of coordinates, but I tried just a simple search for your first coordinate pair:

1. Go to SIMBAD and click the "[coordinate query](https://simbad.u-strasbg.fr/simbad/sim-fcoo)" tab near the top.
2. Then I typed in [your coordinates and selected a 30 arcsec search radius](https://simbad.u-strasbg.fr/simbad/sim-coo?Coord=81.70929343540975%203.0956682931066135&Radius=30&Radius.unit=arcsec). The output is a table of sources near your coordinates, with distances from your coordinates:

[image]

3. It looks like the first row of the search result table is the star you are looking for, so I clicked on the link to go to the [SIMBAD page for psi Ori](https://simbad.cds.unistra.fr/simbad/sim-id?Ident=%40798193&Name=*%20psi02%20Ori).
4. You can skip the first section of "Basic data" and look at the second section, "Identifiers". There you can see that one of the names the object goes by is HD 33715.

Comment: Thank you very much